# CSS: How to line up all the float: left elements perfectly, without gaps?

Tags: css, css-float

Ok, I can't figure this one out... I've got these elements floated left with this:

```css
.event {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

The width is dynamically generated as the browser resizes to adjust for screen size, so I can't control how many of these elements are shown per row and I can't add clear: both break div/lines anywhere because of that (it's all dynamically generated).

[Here is a screenshot of the problem](http://prntscr.com/6x7jwa)

or when resized, another version:

[Another screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6x7lzd)

Now, I've tried both `overflow:hidden` approach, the `clear:both` (which I can't really use), `event::after` approach, and I can't figure out how to set these to line up properly without gaps. If I set the height on them that works just fine, but the height will change dynamically as well and I can't plug in a set height because of that.

Any other ideas?

Comment: why use float: why not display:inline-block?

Comment: You should look into using flex box, it will do exactly what you're attempting to achieve with the floats here, without needing to know how many elements are being displayed per row.

Comment: With variable height your options will be limited. A demo would have been very useful here. If jQuery could be used, I'd recommend the [masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Alternatively, someone created [masonry in CSS3](http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/) but I don't know if the functionality is identical, or you might want to look at CSS columns, if you are happy with the current level of [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=column)

Answer (score 1):

depending on your current viewport size (or parent size) you need to apply a `clear:left` to every `3n + 1` or `4n + 1` `.event` element (you could apply one rule or another using a mediaquery)

```
.event:nth-child(3n + 1) {
   clear:left;
}
```

or

```
.event:nth-child(4n + 1) {
   clear:left;
}
```

Note. When `float` is specified, the `display` property is totally useless (unless you are using `IE6` and you're fighting against the "[double margin bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)")

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a fixed height and then maybe an overflow:scroll; or hidden:

```
.event {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is a raw fiddle demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/ry9qgz3o/

You should set up containers to have the 25% width maybe with a white padding so that your .event elements dont get too close and together.

Comment: I had to go set the height for specific breakpoints using the media query in CSS... the only way to work this out, I guess, as all other suggestions weren't working out.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS , Give **Padding** from all side **0px** To Remove Gaps

```
.event {
display: block;
float: left;
padding:0;
// if you want 5px padding left-right then give property 
// padding:0 5px;

width: 25%;
}
```